# How to generate chart.js labels automatically from array?

Tags: javascript, .net, charts, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to display data from array that contains x and y points but x values interval may not be the same so, how to generate labels of this chart?

Here is an example of what I did

```js
var data = [{x:-0.5,y:-0.5}, {x:1,y:1}, {x:5,y:5}, {x:20,y:20}];

var chartData = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Data',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
            data: data
        }
    ]
};
var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    resposive: true,
    scales: { xAxes: [{ type: 'linear'}] }
};

var mychart= new Chart("myChart", { 
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: You don't have to always set `data.labels`, if both axes are linear there's no need for explicit labels, they are extracted from data. But `[{-0.5,-0.5},{1,1}{5,5},{20,20}]` is not valid javascript, you have to add the keys to [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). If you correct your code and eliminate `data.labels` it should work.

Comment: @kikon thank you for your reply. I set x axe as linear as in the above code but it gives chart with labels of x values in the array and the final chart is not correct

Comment: 1) you have an extra `]` on the first line in the code above, 2) you haven't removed `labels: labels,` line   3) you have `data: chartData` instead of `data: data`. Please make those corrections and we'll see how it looks - I see a line (diagonal) from (-0.5, -0.5) to (20, 20) passing through the other two points.

Comment: @kikon I modified the code as you said but the generated chart now x axis is from 0 to 1 only

Comment: With your code in its latest form, I get [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6L81gau/), which shows the full line.

Comment: I have included a [mcve] from your code, can you describe the problem with this runnable code?

Comment: @kikon Thank you for your effort but I didn't get the same result. I'm using chart.js version v2.9.4. Could the problem be the old version?

Comment: @MariamSultan I have updated the runnable code to use 2.9.4 - this does indeed seem to not work as you probably expect

Comment: Yes, you should specify if you are using a specific old version, otherwise it is assumed to be the latest.

Comment: In version 2.9.4 you should replace `scales: {x: {....}}` (used in versions 3 and later) with `scales:{xAxes:[{....}]}` see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfbn2983/)